# how to execute a stored procedure and store results in temp table for unknown schema

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to execute a stored procedure and store its results to a temp table.I do not know what data would be returned by this stored procedure, so i prefer to create the temp table on the fly.

This is the peice of code i used after surfing lot of sites on getting a way to do this:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #TestTableT FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC [dbo].[aaaaaaa]')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #TestTableT;
```

The problem i encounter is that,after i execute the above code i get

> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1

The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1 Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aaaaaaa'.

Comment: Do you have the stored procedure `Report.IncentiveScheme_DBS` in your database? The error says that it's missing (maybe it is mispelled?)

Comment: It exists in my database,but i dont know y it give this error

Comment: You're executing `[dbo].[aaaaaaa]`. Maybe that's where the error is being generated. Have you reviewed the code of that SP?

Comment: Urgent task implies some payment? Otherwise specify database in your rowset connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must check your procedure code and data in procedure my be you misspell table name

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #TestTableT FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC YourdbName.[dbo].[aaaaaaa]')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #TestTableT;
```